# URI you submitted has disallowed characters for Symbol and Space

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My URL is

```
http://eaxmple.com/career_expert/search_expert/Science & Research
```

How do I remove the symbol to make it work? This is string is stored in the DB.

I have this in `config.php`

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

but it doesn't work.

Error:

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\='; and $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

Comment: but it doesn't work..because in this URL can see the 'Science & Research'.it is searching key..how to solve

Comment: Change the ' & ' to `+%26+`